# select_for_update throws TransactionManagementError within atomic block

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm not super familiar with django but why i'm getting TransactionManagementError when within in atomic block.

```
   with transaction.atomic():
        product = Products.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=product_id).values().first()
        product.available_count = product.available_count - 1
        product.save()
```

Comment: Do you have any `post_save` signals on **`Products`**?

Comment: @spiritsree No I do not, its just the above code inside view method

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.